# Project sequence to multiple sequences using LINQ (or extension methods)

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net, comparative-review, linq

I'm creating a method that expands a sequence.

This is a sample of how it works:

```
Input: {1, 2, 3}
Output: {1}, {1, 2}, {1,2,3}
```

So far, I've been able to solve the algorithm using 2 different approaches:

## Approach 1

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Expand<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    return sequence.Select((x, i) => sequence.Take(i + 1));
}
```

## Approach 2

Using `Aggregate`

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Expand<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    return sequence.Aggregate(new List<List<T>>(), (a, i) =>
    {
        var prev = a.LastOrDefault() ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        var newList = prev.Concat(new[] { i });
        var sources = newList.ToList();
        return a.Concat(new[] { sources }).ToList();
    });
}
```

This one is overly complicated. But it works.

Is there a more elegant way to do this using LINQ or its extension methods?

Comment: Are you interested solutions with Linq or smart solutions without Linq are also playing?

Comment: I've appreciate pure linq solutions better. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 2):

Approach 1 is going to iterate over the `IEnumerable` multiple times. That's against best practices.

Approach 2 is better but still complex. The biggest downside of Aggerate for this solution is we lose the deferred execution and lazy evaluation of the `IEnumerable` and have to consume the entire enumerable before emitting a result.

I think just a normal `foreach` and `yield` will read better and also not have multiple iterations.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Expand<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var buffer = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        buffer.Add(item);
        var result = new T[buffer.Count];
        buffer.CopyTo(result);
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Modified version of Approach #1

- As it was stated by [CharlesNRice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/280248/224104) iterating through an `IEnumerable` multiple times is not ideal
- If the source does not contain too many items then the following alternative might be a better option

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Expand<T>(IEnumerable<T> sourceSequence)
{
    var materializedSequence = sourceSequence.ToArray();
    return materializedSequence.Select((x, i) => materializedSequence[0..(i+1)]);
}
```

- First we materialize the `IEnumerable` to an array
- Then we do more or less what you did except that we rely on the [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#systemrange) construct

### Modified version of Approach #2

- Using the `Aggregate` function is a good direction

  - Your implementation's complexity (*in my humble opinion*) is coming from the usage of wide variety of operators (`LastOrDefault`, `Concat`, `ToList`, `Empty`)
- My alternative solution utilizies only just the `Add` method

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Expand<T>(IEnumerable<T> sourceSequence)
{
    List<IEnumerable<T>> results = new ();
    _ = sourceSequence.Aggregate(new List<T>(), (accumulator, item) =>
    {
        accumulator.Add(item);
        results.Add(new List<T>(accumulator));
        return accumulator;
    });
    return results;
}
```

- First we create a variable for the sequences (`results`)
- Then we call the `Aggregate` to

  - append the `item` to the `accumulator` which is a simple list
  - append the copy of the simple list (`new List<T>(accumulator)`) to the `results`
- We don't care about the result of the `Aggregate` that's why we can use the  discard operator there

Comment: If maintaining state outside a linq operator wouldn't Select be a better choice than Aggregate?  With a select we could keep deferred execution while Aggregate would consume the entire enumerable and lose the lazy evaluation?

Comment: @CharlesNRice I think it depends on the length of the source sequence and how do you plant to use this method. Don't get me wrong I'm not against lazy evaluation, what I try to say it that there are situations where eager evaluation is also fine.

Comment: Yes programming is all about situations.  For me if returning an IEnumerable by default I would assume it's deferred evaluation.  I know even C# breaks that with GroupBy but most do.  If eager I would suggest returning arrays or something that indicates the enumerable has been materialized.  Just my 2 cents.